# Is there a way to feed stdin to VS Code and tell it what filetype to treat it as?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running `git diff | code -` in order to quickly display a diff in VS Code. However, I then have to go to the lower right corner and select "Diff" as the display type in order to get it to do syntax highlighting rather than just show it as plaintext.

I looked at the docs and didn't see what I needed, but maybe I missed something. Is there a way to do something like `git diff| code --ext=diff -` to get it to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the output to a diff file instead i.e. `output.diff` and then open that with code instead of piping directly to code.